# JWT tokens for authentication for 9.1

Tags: identity-server

I want to protect some APIs using OAuth and I want to use Sitecore's new instance of IdentityServer 4. I could just build my own login logic and stick it in the API call. But I would like to use the existing Sitecore.

I found this JwtBearerAuthentication pipeline, but I think it is only used for Azure logins.

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Pipelines.Initialize.JwtBearerAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config">
   <identityProviderName>SitecoreIdentityServer</identityProviderName>
   <audiences hint="raw:AddAudience">
   <audience value="https://SitecoreIdentityServerHost/resources"/>
   </audiences>
   <issuers hint="list">
   <issuer>https://SitecoreIdentityServerHost</issuer>
   </issuers>
</processor>
```

So imagine that a remote application wants to OAuth off of my Sitecore 9.1 Identity server. That seems to be fine, I can get a bearer token from the identity server. But I can not find a pipeline in Sitecore that will accept the bearer token to authorize my APIs.

When I dig into the Sitecore Commerce dlls, I find that the Sitecore .net Core apps are wired up to the identity server and can accept an `Authentication` property in the headers for authenticating bearer tokens. I just don’t see this for Sitecore yet.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:SitecoreIdentityServerUrl").Value;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.EnableCaching = false;
    options.ApiName = "EngineAPI";
    options.ApiSecret = "secret";
});
```

Also this post has provided the best so far for talking to the IS4 https://tothecore.sk/2018/07/25/setting-up-development-environment-with-postman-and-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9/#comment-257

### PowerShell

I found a little more code on how to generate tokens in PowerShell.

To use the PostMan scripts, you need a new client on the indentity server called `postman-api`. Add this to the file \wwwroot\xxx.identityserver\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml. This will allow us to call out custom client for openid.

```
<Clients>
    <DefaultClient>
      <AllowedCorsOrigins>
        <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://habitathome.dev.local|https://habitathomebasic.dev.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
      </AllowedCorsOrigins>
    </DefaultClient>
    <PasswordClient>
      <ClientSecrets>
        <ClientSecret1>ClientSecret</ClientSecret1>
      </ClientSecrets>
    </PasswordClient>
    <PostmanClient>
      <ClientId>postman-api</ClientId>
      <ClientName>postman-api</ClientName>
      <AccessTokenType>0</AccessTokenType>
      <AllowOfflineAccess>true</AllowOfflineAccess>
      <AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken>false</AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken>
      <AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
      <IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
      <AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser>true</AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser>
      <RequireConsent>false</RequireConsent>
      <RequireClientSecret>true</RequireClientSecret>
      <AllowedGrantTypes>
        <AllowedGrantType1>password</AllowedGrantType1>
      </AllowedGrantTypes>
      <AllowedCorsOrigins>
      </AllowedCorsOrigins>
      <AllowedScopes>
        <AllowedScope1>openid</AllowedScope1>
        <AllowedScope2>sitecore.profile</AllowedScope2>
        <AllowedScope3>sitecore.profile.api</AllowedScope3>
      </AllowedScopes>
      <ClientSecrets>
        <ClientSecret1>ClientSecret</ClientSecret1>
      </ClientSecrets>
      <UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh>true</UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh>
    </PostmanClient>
</Clients>
```

Finally you can use this PowerShell to generate a token. https://gist.github.com/johnkors/454c829aa63e7663745da5ebeb38dd86

The only issue I still have is that Sitecore will not validate the JWT token. My error is:

> 8604 01:14:45 ERROR Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware - Authentication failed
>
> Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException
>   Message: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
>
> Source: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) in C:\agent2_work\15\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 1057 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken) in C:\agent2_work\15\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 768
>   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat.Unprotect(String protectedText)
>   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: Hey Chris, have you looked at the JWT token you receive from identity server already using https://jwt.io/ ? It sounds like the validation of the signature of the token is failing. What Audience value are you using?

Comment: @IvanL When I used the pub/priv key that created the jwt token, it validates fine on  jwt.io. I am not using an audience at all. Just grant, client_id, client_secret and scope.

Comment: I would have thought you'd need to create a custom subprovider on the identity server as per https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/add-a-runtime-plugin-manually.html and https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got back the answer on using the right token for authentication with iDentity server Bearer tokens.

For anyone who comes behind, a sharable Postman set of APi calls can be found here. https://www.getpostman.com/collections/a98dc7091c404c879b77

Here is the basic super simple controller that returns json data. The important part is the [Authorize] attribute. This forces the controller through whatever security is registered with MVC.

```
public class MembershipController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var test = new {TestError = "this thing"};

        return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In the image below, this is how you make a call to the identity server (https://sc910.identityserver/connect/token) to get the bearer token from the Sitecore identity server. You can find the client secret at `\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` in the root of the identity server.

The key to making this work is that the grant_type is `password` and client_id is `SitecorePassword`. When executed you will get a token.

[image]

Then we can call our api passing in the bearer token, in the header as the variable `Authorization`. You must add the word `Bearer` before your token. When executed, Sitecore with authentication you token and give you access.

[image]

Comment: I can't get this to work in sitecore 9.2. Did you have to change any other configs?
I'm able to authenticate using ssc token, but not SI server token.